# "omp_get_num_threads" in "pragma omp parallel for" is giving me compile error

Tags: c, openmp

I am getting

> error: for statement expected before ‘printf’

in my code:

```
float *vector_matrix_product(float *A, int m, int n, float *x)
{
    float *b = (float*) calloc(m, sizeof(float));

    #pragma omp parallel for default(none) shared(A,m,n,x,b), private(i,j)
            printf("Threads: %d\n", omp_get_num_threads()); // << here
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    b[i] += A[i * n + j] * x[j];
                }
            }

    return b;
}
```

because I wish to determine the number of threads in my parallel region. What's the mistake? Do I need brackets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#pragma omp parallel for` statement should occur on the line right before the `for` loop.

If you would like to spawn threads and not immediately use them for the `for` loop, you can spawn the threads first using `#pragma omp parallel`. This spawns the threads. Then you can add additional lines of code like printf, etc.

And later when you want to use the threads for the `for` loop, write `#pragma omp for` just before the `for` loop. This way, you won't get the error.

E.g.

```
#pragma omp parallel
    printf("something");
    #pragma omp for
      for(...){}
```